# Escape single quotation in vector of strings

Tags: r, gsub

I want to escape single quotation marks in a vector (for example to execute a SQL query), but I'm unable to do so.

Example code:

```
strings <- c("ef'gh")
strings2 <- gsub("'", "\'", strings)
cat(strings2)
print(strings2)
```

Expected output of either cat or print:

```
ef\'gh
"ef\'gh"
```

But none of the above. I tried multiple other combinations already, with different ways of escaping quotation, without success.

Comment: try `strings2 <- gsub("'", "\\'", strings, fixed = TRUE); cat(strings2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```
strings <- c("ef'gh")
strings2 <- sub("\'", "\\\\'", strings)

cat(strings2)
  [1] ef\'gh
print(strings2)
  [1] "ef\\'gh"
```